# How to pass value given by javascript variables to PHP variables?

Tags: php, ajax

I want the variables like `screen width` `screen height` `color depth` and `pixel depth` to be used in a PHP function. Basically what I want to do is when user come in my webpage eg:`localhost/try.php` I want to know all above mentioned details of client without setting cookies or session properties or get parameters. Yeah and of course without reloading the page. I know `php` but not AJAX so can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. If you want help here, then you need to ask a _specific_ question, usually pertaining to a problem with code you have already written. The only acceptable response here to “I don’t know Ajax” should IMHO be, well start and go read up on the basics of it then. This site is not a teaching ground for the absolutely elementary stuff, that you can easily go read up on yourself elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood it right, your question is When user comes to your page(e.g try.php)how to pass javascript variable(e.g screen.width screen.height) to PHP section so that you can make it as a PHP variable.

Here is a working solution.

try.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" id="screenWidth" name="screenWidth">
        <input type="hidden" id="screenHeight" name="screenHeight">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("screenWidth").value = screen.width;
        document.getElementById("screenHeight").value = screen.height;

        function autoSubmit () 
        {
            let form = document.getElementById("myForm");
            form.submit();
        }
        window.onload = autoSubmit;
    </script>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'POST')
    {
        if(!empty($_POST["screenWidth"]))
        {   
            $screenWidth = $_POST["screenWidth"];
            echo $screenWidth; // see if it gets the screen.width
        }
        if(!empty($_POST["screenHeight"]))
        {   
            $screenHeight = $_POST["screenHeight"];
            echo $screenHeight; // see if it gets the screen.height
        }
    }
?>
```

It basically manipulate the DOM and change the value of input value to be the screen.width and screen.height and then submit the form automatically when the window is onload.

If the the server received an HTTP POST method input then it checks the name of the POST inputs and save it into each PHP variables.